# Why is the type inferred for my ML function different than I expect?

Tags: types, type-inference, ml

I made function that's name is `maptree`. And below is my code:

```
datatype 'a tree = LEAF of 'a | NODE of 'a tree * 'a tree;
fun maptree(f, NODE(X, Y)) = NODE(maptree(f, X), maptree(f, Y))
| maptree(f, LEAF(X)) = LEAF(f X);
```

I expected maptree to have the type

```
 ('a -> 'a) -> 'a tree -> 'a tree
```

but the type inferred by the compiler is

```
 ('a -> 'b) * 'a tree -> 'b tree
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Hindley-Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) type-inference algorithm allows you to get more general type than you expected.

When the algorithm tries to infer the type for `maptree`, it assumes that `f: 'a -> 'b` (from the fact you're using `f` as a function). And nothing restricts the type of `f` further.

If you, for example, defined the `maptree` function as follows (I used `f` twice in the `LEAF` case):

```
fun maptree(f, NODE(X, Y)) = NODE(maptree(f, X), maptree(f, Y))
  | maptree(f, LEAF(X)) = LEAF(f (f X))
```

Then the type-inference mechanism would have to restrict the type of `f` to `'a -> 'a` (since we feed the output of the function to its input).

The output of SML/NJ for the modified case:

```
val maptree = fn : ('a -> 'a) * 'a tree -> 'a tree
```